# Windows 10 unconditional startup BSOD; can't read file system(?)

Tags: windows-10, boot, filesystems, bsod

### Mostly irrelevant(?) backstory

My Windows 10 laptop was working fine before its bimonthly restart. I had closed most programs, except Firefox, an hour or two before `shutdown /s /t 00`. There was a pending File Menu Tools post-install restart which I had ignored, hibernating at least twice in the meantime. I closed Firefox before the shutdown. I then left the laptop for about 15 minutes.

<s>I have no backups. As soon as my laptop is fixed, I promise I'll make one if the data's still there.</s> (Edit: I'm making a disk image using `dd` on a Ubuntu disk at the moment.)

### Problem

Upon turning my computer back on, I was greeted with a BSOD. I didn't pay attention to the stop code. I left it too long, and was greeted to an Automatic Repair loading screen. I left this to load for several minutes before it occurred to me that the machine was powering on and off much more than expected.

It turns out that the machine is stuck in a loop, attempting to load Windows before being greeted with a `NTFS FILE SYSTEM` BSOD. It then tried to fix itself, flashing a `conhost` window(?) (EDIT: `winpeshl.exe`, italics, Windows 7 sans Aero-style title bar) for a split second, then a 1-3 second pause, then a `FAT FILE SYSTEM` BSOD.

I don't know whether the computer applied Windows Updates in the time I was gone. I'm hoping it's just a corrupt kernel.

What's wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Use your windows CD to access CMD

Simply by getting to the point where it say's install now, click it then wait. Once your at next option hold down SHIFT and press F10. You will given a CMD with Admin Rights,

Now try repairing your boot file with the following commands.

http://thewindowsclub.thewindowsclubco.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/image20.png

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]

X:\windows\system32>bootrec /RebuildBcd
Scanning all disks for Windows installations.

Please wait, since this may take a while...

Successfully scanned Windows installations.
Total identified Windows installations: 0
The operation completed successfully.

X:\windows\system32>bootrec /fixMbr
The operation completed successfully

X:\windows\system32>bootrec /fixboot
The operation completed successfully

X:\windows\system32>
```

Comment: This looks promising. Where did you get this information from? I know it was The Windows Club, but where?

Comment: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=bootrec+%2FRebuildBcd&rlz=1C1CHBD_en-GBAU784AU784&oq=bootrec+%2FRebuildBcd&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

## Windows Automatic Recovery Method via USB or DVD

1. [Obtain Windows 10 iso.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)
2. Install to flash drive or DVD. [You can use rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)
3. You will have to make your BIOS boot to the flash drive or DVD drive first. (You'll have to look up how your computer make and model gets to the BIOS. Typically you can hammer the ESC key on boot but every computer is different.)
4. Boot from storage then attempt automatic repairs. It should have an option somewhere instead of clicking install you would click repair.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation the first thing I would do is pull your HDD out an place it in a computer. I would run a program called Easeus Recovery Software. That way you know you will get your data back.

Once you have backed up your data I would try the following 10 steps running in safe mode... Windows always install's in the same section on your HDD not over your pictures. Try disabling Shadowing Caching in your bios, make sure your ram is clean from dust.

1: Repair Registry Entries Associated with Error
2: Conduct a Full Malware Scan of Your PC
3: Clean Out Your System Junk (Temporary Files and Folders) With Disk Cleanup (cleanmgr)
4: Update Your PC Device Drivers
5: Utilize Windows System Restore to "Undo" Recent System Changes
6: Uninstall and Reinstall the Windows Operating System Program Associated with NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM
7: Run Windows System File Checker ("sfc /scannow")
8: Install All Available Windows Updates
9: Check for Hard Drive Corruption ("chkdsk /f")
10: Test Your Memory (RAM) for Corruption
11: Perform a Clean Installation of Windows

Use Acronis to make a backup, constantly back up your data from now on. Hope this works?

I got the information from here, https://www.solvusoft.com/en/errors/blue-screen-errors/microsoft-corporation/windows-operating-system/bug-check-0x24-ntfs-file-system/

Once I realised your data was in trouble I knew how you felt. I have been there before.

Comment: I'm making a backup using `dd`; the data's there although the filesystem's a bit messed up. Unfortunately this doesn't help as I can't even boot Windows, let alone access the registry. That website seems to be a semi-spammy commission website to get you to download those programs; it's giving generic advice and linking to the same products repeatedly.

Comment: I have easeus recovery if you want it

Comment: If it's free, I can get it myself. If not, I don't want to pirate it. I don't need it anyway; my file system is readable, if not safely writable. Thanks for the offer anyway.

Comment: It's not pirate, All my tools are from teachers in my classes

Comment: But if I would need to buy a license, _my_ copy (the one you gave me) would be pirated.

Comment: The government gave me this equipment, nothing is pirated. Haven't you been a student before. You get key's to almost anything?

Comment: Yes, but _you're not allowed to give them to random people on the internet_.