# Laptop rejects Windows 10 but Debian and Ubuntu work fine

Tags: windows-10, bsod, toshiba-laptop

or, [Windows 10 unconditional startup BSOD; can't read file system(?)](https://superuser.com/q/1296123/541767) part 2.

---

My Windows 10 Toshiba Satellite C50-B-14Z was working fine before its bi-monthly restart.

Then something snapped in its <del>positronic</del> electronic circuits.

I don't know why, but it now refuses to run any sort of Windows 10 at all. Windows 10 proper crashes before it renders anything other than the spinny wheel (not even the mouse cursor). Windows 10 recovery mode crashes shortly after it runs its first `conhost` program. The Windows 10 install disk dies when I try to select a language (or even if I don't select a language). The Windows 10 recovery medium also dies.

How do they crash? With a Blue Screen of Death. Specifically, a `filesystem FILE SYSTEM` error. `NTFS` for Windows proper, `FAT` for everything else. When the system is started normally, these cycle in a strangely hypnotic pattern... but I digress.

I booted the Debian install disk, hoping to use `ddrescue`, then switched to the Ubuntu install disk when I realised that I couldn't access `apt-get` from the recovery console, and made a disk image. There were only three bad reads, which read perfectly well on the second pass; the drive wasn't somehow at fault.

Then it occurred to me that Debian and Ubuntu had *booted fine*, aside from the Debian graphical installer having no mouse support.

⸘What is going on here‽

---

<sup>I determined that the [ghost](/questions/tagged/ghost) tag was not appropriate in this case, [however much I wanted it to be](https://xkcd.com/1316/).</sup>

Comment: You state "The Windows 10 install disk dies..." Have you gone to the Windows ISO download and created a flash USB? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: I created an install DVD from an ISO on the Microsoft website. It works on other machines.

Comment: Some PC's don't boot from DVD because drivers are not yet loaded. No guarantee, but USB *might* work where DVD does not.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It's a USB disk drive, and it boots Debian / Ubuntu fine when loaded in the same way. I'll try USB thunk drive once I have a free one.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I've even had to use a USB DVD drive instead of the internal one on a laptop before to install windows 7. No joke.